# Как досрочно остановить рекурсию

Tags: python, рекурсия

У меня есть код, который из значения **`100`** рекурсивно уменьшается до **`0`** вычитая **`20`**.

Вопрос, можно ли досрочно остановить, или поставить точку остановки  и вывести например первую итерацию, чтобы я мог далее обращаться к данному значению?

```
def  req(value):
        if value <= 0:
            print("Конечный итог 0")
            return 
        else:
            print("Данное значение:", value)
            return req(value - 20)
```

Comment: К какому данному значению? И как именно обращаться?

Comment: чтобы например при вызове req(100) я мог получить значение 100, затем 80, но отдельно а не полным циклом
например записать в переменную temp = req(100) значение 100

Comment: `def  req(value): return value`

Comment: Попытка изобрести генератор? А чем вас простой `range(100,-1,-20)` не устраивает?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы я мог обращаться к каждому значению до самого 0, то есть, чтобы каждый раз вызывал функцию, у меня там было значение 80, потом вызов и 60 и тд.
Все это можно сделать через while, но интересно узнать можно ли сделать это через рекурсию

Answer (score 3):

Используя генератор можно сделать так

```
def req(value):
    yield value
    if value <= 0:
        print("Конечный итог 0")
        return
    else:
        print("Данное значение:", value)
        yield from req(value - 20)


for x in req(100):
    print(x)
```

результат

```
100
Данное значение: 100
80
Данное значение: 80
60
Данное значение: 60
```

и так далее

Comment: Прощу прощения, немного не так поставил вопрос, мне нужно чтобы после каждой итерации рекурсии она выходила из цикла, то есть:
Я вызываю функцию req, она возвращает 80 и останавливается, затем я вновь вызываю функцию и получаю уже 60

Comment: `def  req(value): return value-20` Те в функции просто выполняйте одну итерацию. Используя partial   можно настроить один раз параметры итерации

Answer (score 0):

Можно попытаться ввести счетчик итераций, если я вас правильно понял.

```
def req(value, count):
    if value <= 0:
        # print("Конечный итог 0")
        return
    elif count == 0:  # Прошло заданное количество итераций
        return value
    else:
        # print("Данное значение:", value)
        count -= 1  # Счетчик
        return req(value - 20, count)


count = int(input("Какую итерацию вы хотите получить: "))
temp = req(100, count)
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить:

```py
iterator = iter(range(100, -1, -20))


def get_next():
    try:
        return next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return 0


print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
```

Вывод

```latex
100
80
60
40
20
0
0
0
```

или вариант с зацикленным итератором:

```py
default_range = range(100, -1, -20)

iterator = iter(default_range)


def get_next():
    global iterator
    try:
        return next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        iterator = iter(default_range)
        return next(iterator)


print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
print(get_next())
```

Вывод

```latex
100
80
60
40
20
0
100
80
```

Если еще нагляднее то:

```py
default_range = range(100, -1, -20)

iterator = iter(default_range)


def get_next():
    global iterator
    try:
        return next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        iterator = iter(default_range)
        return next(iterator)


print(
    f'First value = {get_next()}, Second value = {get_next()}'
)
```

Вывод

```latex
First value = 100, Second value = 80
```